# PHP - Check if more than one condition is true in a given number of conditions

Tags: php

Is there an elegant way to check if multiple, but not all, conditions are true out of any given number of conditions?

For example, I have three variables: $a, $b, and $c.
I want to check that any two of these are true. So the following would pass:

```
$a = true;
$b = false;
$c = true;
```

But this wouldn't:

```
$a = false;
$b = false;
$c = true;
```

Also, I may want to check if 4 out of 7 conditions were true, for example.

I realise I can check each combination, but this would get more difficult as the number of conditions increased. Looping through the conditions and keeping a tally is the best option I can think of, but I thought there may be a different way to do this.

Thanks!

Edit: Thanks for all the great answers, they're much appreciated.
Just to throw a spanner in to the works, what if the variables weren't explicit booleans?
E.g.

```
($a == 2)
($b != "cheese")
($c !== false)
($d instanceof SomeClass)
```

Comment: Do you want "more than 1, but not all" or do you want "exactly x out of y"?

Comment: Do you have the count of variables ? e.g. for first case it's 3 and for second it's 7.

Comment: I'm looking for a solution that is flexible for different circumstances. Ideally, a solution that had the option of a range (i.e. between 2 and 4 out of 7) would be great. However, that could be used to say "between 2 and 2" - i.e. exactly 2 - if that makes sense :)

Comment: I don't think there's anything more elegant than just looping your conditions and keeping track. You can make some functions that accept arrays and numbers, but that's about it.

Comment: Your latest requirement shouldn't throw any spanners into the works, as all the expressions you give result in boolean values; there should be no difference between evaluating those and evaluating a boolean variable. For example, try `var_dump($d instanceof SomeClass);`; you'll find the result will be `bool(false)`, indicating that you've been given an explicitly boolean value as the result.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[A "true" boolean in PHP casts to a 1 as an integer, and "false" casts to 0](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php). Hence:

```
echo $a + $b +$c;
```

...will output 2 if two out of the three boolean variables `$a`, `$b` or `$c` are true. (Adding the values will implicitly convert them to integers.)

This will also work with functions like [`array_sum()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php), so for example:

```
echo array_sum([true == false, 'cheese' == 'cheese', 5 == 5, 'moon' == 'green cheese']);
```

...will output 2.

Comment: Would that work in the same way for:
($a == 2) + ($b != "cheese") + ($c !== false)?

Comment: Yes, it would as each test would return `true` or `false`

Answer (score 5):

You could put your variables in an array, and use [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) and [`count()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) to check the number of true values:

```
$a = true;
$b = false;
$c = true;

if (count(array_filter(array($a, $b, $c))) == 2) {
    echo "Success";
};
```

Comment: All variables should not be `true` according to OP.

Comment: @AlokPatel Gotcha. Updated.

Comment: You might need to add `||` for the count of array_filter. It should be greater or equal to 2 and should not be total of all variables.

Comment: @AlokPatel Why? `array_filter()` filters out all the true values, and `count()` counts the result of that operation. And according to OP, there should be any two out of three that are true, so strict equals.

Comment: May be OP is looking for `two ore more` and `not all`. So You will need to check with `&&` for these two conditions.

Comment: @AlokPatel OP states: "I want to check that any two of these are true." If two or more is also OK, than the condition should be changed to greater than or equals instead of equals, that's all.

Comment: OP's first line is "Is there an elegant way to check if **multiple**, but **not all**."

Comment: @AlokPatel You're just guessing. My answer clearly demonstrates how to do the count for any given number of values. All the rest is just simple comparison.

Comment: Thanks @RobbyCornelissen. Would this work if the variables weren't explicit booleans (E.g. ($a == 2) + ($b != "cheese") + ($c !== false))?

Comment: It will filter out all the "truthy" values. See the documentation for `array_filter` for an example. In your comment, all the variables are boolean. `($a == 2)`, as well as `($b != "cheese)` and `($c !== false)` resolve to a boolean.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go for a method like the following:

```
if (evaluate(a, b, c))
{
    do stuff;
}

boolean evaluate(boolean a, boolean b, boolean c) 
{
    return a ? (b || c) : (b && c);
}
```

What it says is:

- If a is True, then one of b or c must be true too to comply with 2/3
  True criterion.
- Else, both b and c must be true!

If you want to expand and customise the conditions and the number of variables I'd go for for a solution like the following:

```
$a = true;
$b = true;
$c = true;
$d = false;
$e = false;
$f = true;

$condition = 4/7;

$bools = array($a, $b, $c, $d, $e, $f);

$eval = count(array_filter($bools)) / sizeof($bools);

print_r($eval / $condition >= 1 ? true : false);
```

Simply we evaluate the true's and we make sure that the % of True is equals or is better than what we want to achieve. Likewise you could manipulate the final evaluation expression to achieve what you want.

Comment: I didn't quite get that "4 out of 7". Does he mean 4 boolean expressions out of 7?

Comment: @Manos, that is really nice.

Comment: @ManosForsaken Yeah, I wondered if there was a flexible solution for any number of true conditions out of any number of conditions. I only specifically need 2 out of 3 at the moment, but will likely need other amounts in the future.

Answer (score 1):

This should also work, and would allow you fairly easily to adjust to the numbers.

```
$a = array('soap','soap');
$b = array('cake','sponge');
$c = array(true,true);
$d = array(5,5);
$e = false;
$f = array(true,true);
$g = array(false,true);
$pass = 4;
$ar = array($a,$b,$c,$d,$e,$f,$g);

var_dump(trueornot($ar,$pass));

function trueornot($number,$pass = 2){
    $store = array();
    foreach($number as $test){
        if(is_array($test)){
            if($test[0] === $test[1]){
                $store[] = 1;
            }
        }else{
            if(!empty($test)){
                $store[] = 1;   
            }
        }    
        if(count($store) >= $pass){
            return TRUE;    
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks good just for boolean variables - although it would need some tweaking for other types of variables.

Comment: @SixTicksLimited it should now.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a little easy and short writing when you use operator "&" , "|" like this:

```
$a = true;
$b = true;
$c = false;

$isTrue = $a&$b | $b&$c | $c&$a;

print_r( $isTrue );
```

Let check by your self :D

Answer (score 0):

U can use while loop :

```
$condition_n = "x number"; // number of required true conditions
$conditions = "x number"; // number of conditions
$loop = "1";
$condition = "0";

while($loop <= $conditions)
{
 // check if condition is true
 // if condition is true : $condition = $condition + 1;
 // $loop = $loop + 1;
}
if($condition >= $condition_n)
{
 // conditions is True
}
else
{
 // conditions is false
}
```

Comment: Yeah, this is the kind of loop I suggested in the question - it just seemed a bit long winded.